# django personal filter datetime

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-filter, django-template-filters

I want find the number of days between a date et the date 15 days after.
I create a personnal filter :

```
register = template.Library()

import datetime

@register.filter
def nbDays(thedate):
    res = 0
    passed = datetime.datetime.now() - thedate
    res = 15 - passed   
return res
```

I have this error :

```
can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

When I call the method :

```
{% load nameOfFile %}

{{ objectGood.created_at|nbDays }}
```

Comment: Do you have `USE_TZ = True` in your settings?

Comment: No I search how uses it

Comment: Is true : I have this USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

Answer (score 0):

If you've got timezones enabled in your settings then you need to make all of your `datetime` objects timezone aware.

Django makes this pretty easy;

```
register = template.Library()

from django.utils import timezone

@register.filter
def nbDays(thedate):
    res = 0
    passed = timezone.now() - thedate
    res = 15 - passed   
return res
```

Alternatively you can remove the timezone awareness from a datetime object;

`timezone_unaware_date = thedate.replace(tzinfo=None)`

Comment: It don't works, I have this error : unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'.   But I find a solution : now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc) but I don't know totally. Thanks

Comment: You're doing `15 - passed` where `passed` is a datetime object hense the type error. You need to look at `relativedelta` if you want to start making addition/subtraction of days etc from datetime objects. http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-72c4689ec5608067d118b9143cef6bdffb6dad4e